# WP Website is shown in HTML

Tags: php, css, html

I‘ve been experiencing quite a strange issue with my WP website since I’ve upgraded my WP to the version 5.4.2.

From time to time (it can occur to 2-3 times / week) my Website is displayed as html Code on all the devices / in all the browsers (pls take a look at the Screenshot). The problem disappears as soon as I log in into the WP dashboard - no further actions are required.

I‘ve checked the plug-ins - they are all compatible. There are also no errors detected in the WP Website Status.

Has anyone any hint for me what could cause such a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Jana
[image]

Comment: Hi Jana, my first check would be to speak with the hosts on this one I think. You'll need to see whether there is any form of caching running on the site / server and see whether the server that you're on is hitting any sort of limits or if any issues are listed in the error_log found in usually public_html when you FTP in. If you have any caching plugins installed, try disabling them for a week.

Comment: This is probably what your site looks like when it can load the HTML but not the CSS. So you're seeing the content of your page properly but the stylesheets are failing to load. A good way to diagnose this is when it's happening use a desktop browser with the development tools and look at the 'Network' section to see what's happening with your CSS files.